# AWS python Lambda can't access EFS files

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I'm trying to have python lambda use EFS as library storage, but it seems it can't get the contents of it.
so this code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/mnt/efs/features")
import pandas as pd
```

Doesn't work on lambda, however  when i mount the EFS from c9 same code works (I'm sure that the c9 python installation doesn't have pandas itself).

I tried doing

```
logger.info(os.path.ismount("/mnt/efs"))
```

which logs True, then I tried

```
logger.info(os.listdir("/mnt/efs"))
```

which logs empty array

I've defined local path for lambda file system as /mnt/efs and in c9 env i see that the features directory is created there, in efs I see that the size matches. access point is defined with root path /efs and has 777 permissions. Any ideas what I'm missing would be appriciated.

Comment: Does `/efs` or `/mnt/efs/` have `777` permissions? Because if you mean the permissions of `/efs` as a symbolic link , that most likely doesn't matter. See e.g. [this stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87200/change-permissions-for-a-symbolic-link)

Comment: The root directory on access point is 777 so I don't think it's related to the symlink issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was where I had placed features dir in EFS. the access point had defined root as /efs but I had put it via c9 into /features, after moving features to /efs/features it worked fine.